# Deployment error with xamarin.forms application in device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, device

My project is running in emulator without any issue. But when I select my device to run the application, it says deployment error. Device's android version is : 6.0.1 and I have API 23 installed in my machine. error is like this :

```
Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install output:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]
```

Edit : I have tested it with another phone. It's working in that phone. So, the issues is obviously in the phone.

Comment: Do you try your YourProject.Android -> Properties -> Android Options -> Use Shared Runtime -> Remove click (Can be empty) and rebuild.

Comment: It is probably missing the images for that device.